# Should mod_proxy_ajp or mod_jk be used for a production environment?

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, mod-jk

I've been searching over the past few days of whether I should use mod_proxy_ajp or mod_jk to connect apache httpd and tomcat. All the sites I find are a few years old and outdated.

So, which is best to use for a proper production environment? Is mod_proxy_ajp mature enough to entirely replace mod_jk, or is mod_jk still best if you can configure it correctly? Also, what's the difference in difficulty when configuring each connector?

Comment: possible duplicate of [apache to tomcat: mod\_jk vs mod\_proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081918/apache-to-tomcat-mod-jk-vs-mod-proxy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had mod_jk in production for about 4 years. It does what it's supposed to, and I don't have to think about it. I have no reason to change it.

For a new server I'd stick to what I already know works, unless there was a compelling reason not to.

The functionality isn't a complete overlap. I also remember reading somewhere that mod_jk is faster.