# Server Setup: Based on Apache and Tomcat needs

Tags: apache, tomcat, web, socialengine

I'm trying to setup a server based on our needs for a new website.  Basically, I need to build a website based on social engine, and according to the platform's requirements (found here: http://www.socialengine.net/support/documentation/article?q=152&question=SocialEngine-Requirements) it requires the webserver to be Apache based.

Now my issue comes with the addition of a web application that needs to be included in the site.  The web application requires the server to be capable of Asynchronous Request Processing, and is currently only supported by Tomcat or GlassFish.

I found a couple tutorials such as this one http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/2203891/Integrating-Tomcat-with-Apache.htm that explain how to "integrate" Tomcat into Apache.  Would a server running Tomcat alone be able to handle the applet needs as well as serve the Apache (assuming HTTP) needs from the Social Engine platform?  Are there any hosting providers any of you would reccomend?

Although I've done alot of front end stuff before, this is the first time i have to deal with any of the back end details, so  my knowledge of server side functionality is really garbage.  Please let me know if I'm not asking the right questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't really be able to use Tomcat for both apps, since the other one needs PHP. It's pretty common to have both Tomcat and Apache running on the same server. You might want to look up more recent documentation on mixing them, even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081918/apache-to-tomcat-mod-jk-vs-mod-proxy) but definitely have a look at  [mod_proxy_ajp](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html).

What's the other application? It's a little tricky to set up Asynchronous Request Processing if you are new to server apps, but there is also a lot of documentation, so if you're game, you can probably figure it out OK. You might also want to see if that app would work with [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) (hosting info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648993/where-can-i-host-a-node-js-app))

If you want to set it all up yourself, you could get a virtual private server from [Rackspace Cloud](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/?id=394) or similar host or get a shared host that has the required apps already set up, which would limit your ability to customize the environment and may require 2 hosting plans, but would be easier to set up. It also somewhat depends on if both apps need to be on the same machine for any reason and/or on the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

A regular LAMP stack will run SE4 just fine, however, you will need to do some tuning to get the page loads under 3 seconds. You will want to remove any Apache modules that you aren't using with `a2dismod`.  For instance, if you're not using any Ruby on the site, `a2dismod ruby`.  This will help get memory usage under control.  [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC) is a must.

For a much more in depth read on tuning php/apache, please read this: [Performance tuning on Apache, PHP, MySQL, WordPress v1.1 – Updated](http://blog.mydream.com.hk/howto/linux/performance-tuning-on-apache-php-mysql-wordpress)