# Apache2 mod_jk segfaults with OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, apache, apache2, mod-jk, osx-mavericks

I upgraded to Mavericks just yesterday, and had to reinstall mod_jk for my development environment. Compiling it from source was a bit of a pain. I found [this page](http://www.bartbusschots.ie/blog/?p=1347) on a [previously-asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711009/how-to-install-mod-jk-on-mac-os-x) about mod_jk on OS X, but there were a couple extra hoops I had to jump through. For some reason, apxs thinks that gcc lives at:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
```

But that exact folder doesn't exist; I had to symlink the existing `XcodeDefault.xctoolchain` directory:

```
sudo ln -s XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/ OSX10.9.xctoolchain
```

Then I tried running configure:

```
./configure CFLAGS='-arch x86_64' APXSLDFLAGS='-arch x86_64' --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs
```

However, configure failed because it couldn't find `<stdio.h>`, so I symlinked the OS X 10.9 toolchain as so:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/ /usr/include
```

I was able to then compile and install the module by running `sudo make install -f Makefile.apxs` in the apache-2.0 subdirectory. However, when I started up Apache via `sudo apachectl start`, it immediately crashes with a segfault:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x00007fff875fb866 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8b8a435c pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff92480bba abort + 125
3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff92480d31 abort_report_np + 181
4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff924a48c5 __chk_fail + 48
5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff924a48d5 __chk_fail_overlap + 16
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff924a4906 __chk_overlap + 49
7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff924a4ad1 __strcpy_chk + 64
8   mod_jk.so                           0x0000000105a0c631 jk_map_get_int + 225
9   mod_jk.so                           0x0000000105a1f7f1 jk_get_worker_maintain_time + 33
10  mod_jk.so                           0x0000000105a17683 wc_open + 755
11  mod_jk.so                           0x0000000105a2f13f init_jk + 1151
12  mod_jk.so                           0x0000000105a28b7e jk_post_config + 1566
13  httpd                               0x000000010568b7d5 ap_run_post_config + 133
14  httpd                               0x00000001056947c7 main + 2567
15  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff9176e5fd start + 1
```

Has anyone had success compiling/running mod_jk with Mavericks yet? Is there something I'm missing or not doing quite right?

Comment: Just found out this might be relevant: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55696

Comment: The bug reported in bugzilla actually solves the issue for all of us in the office on Mavericks. Cheers thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aforementioned [bug reported against Tomcat](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55696) has a proposed patch which is likely to be applied soon. Feel free to use any of the patches described in that bug -- they will all work.

Answer (score 2):

Download latest Tomcat Connectors source from tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi

Per https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55696
change the method below in ./native/common/jk_maps.c to what you see here:

```
int jk_map_get_int(jk_map_t *m, const char *name, int def)
 {
     const char *rc;
     int int_res;

    rc = jk_map_get_string(m, name, NULL);

    if(NULL == rc) {
        int_res = def;
    } else {
        size_t len = strlen(rc);
        int multit = 1;

        if (len) {
            char buf[100];
            char *lastchar;
             strncpy(buf, rc, 100);
            lastchar = buf + len - 1;
            if ('m' == *lastchar || 'M' == *lastchar) {
                *lastchar = '\0';
                multit = 1024 * 1024;
            }
            else if ('k' == *lastchar || 'K' == *lastchar) {
                *lastchar = '\0';
                multit = 1024;
            }
            int_res = multit * atoi(buf);
        }
        else
            int_res = def;
     }
    return int_res;
 }
```

Install command line tools

xcode-select --install

Create missing symlink

sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain

cd ./native

./configure CFLAGS='-arch x86_64' APXSLDFLAGS='-arch x86_64' --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs

chmod 755 scripts/build/instdso.sh

make

sudo make install

Answer (score 1):

WORKAROUND - NOT A SOLUTION

I am encountering the same thing and was unable to get **mod_jk** to run inside of Apache.

As an alternative to simply get it to work locally and keep moving forward, I changed a few of the apache directives around to use **mod_proxy_ajp** instead.

```
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ajp.so

ProxyPassMatch ^(/.*\.(jsp|json))$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1
ProxyPass /aircharge ajp://localhost:8009/aircharge
...
```

Since the AJP protocol is still being used, the same connector for Tomcat can be used without modification.