# Apache as front to Tomcat with proxy with mod_proxy_ajp on Mavericks Mac

Tags: apache, tomcat, osx-mavericks

I want to front Tomcat with Apache on a new Mac Server but Im missing some minor step. At the moment both servers are running, but port 8009 is not proxied correctly.  80 and 8080 is working.

I read that Mac/Apache has mod_proxy_ajp installed and should also be ready to run.
(Mentioned by for example Vladimir [How to install mod_jk on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711009/how-to-install-mod-jk-on-mac-os-x/11711785#11711785))

Can someone guide me step by step on a new server from scratch, since all guides on internet, and documentations has not lead to success.  (Sorry for asking, but im stuck after 1 week of nightly trials(errors). Im really going nuts here.  I would appreciate folderpaths too, since files sometimes are located on more than one location)

Thanks in advance!

Regards
Niklas

Comment: Found one error. I need to watchout for correct filepaths. I thought Apache was configured in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf.  But when Server.app is installed this file is copied to /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf.  Maybee this is one of the errors.   Maybee this is the file to change? I will try.

Comment: Yes this was the case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, I was not allowed to answer my own question within 8 hrs (lack of points) but **Yes I got it working!**    Mavericks Mac OSX server is really easy to setup and use with Apache as front to Tomcat. (If you know how to....)

Now I have tomcat integrated so that php with url: localhost is handeled by Apache and jsp url: localhost/examples -> runs tomcat but doesnt show the port, it looks integrated.

How I did it?

1) Uncomment if neccessary the line in server.xml for tomcat located in opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/conf:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Restart the tomcat server

2) Edit the Apache config file located:  /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf

This strange name and location is caused by Mac Server.app and was what caused most problems, since I did not realize they renamed and copied the httpd.conf file to a second location! I was all the time changing the wrong config file...

I added this text with a texteditor TextMate (The program can show hidden files, and ask for adminpass when changing the file)

The Default webpage in Mac.Server is located as below Document Root

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
   ServerName localhost 
   DocumentRoot "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default"

   <Proxy *> 
    AddDefaultCharset Off 
    Order deny,allow 
    Allow from localhost 
   </Proxy> 
   ProxyPass /examples ajp://localhost:8009/examples/ 
   ProxyPassReverse /examples ajp://localhost:8009/examples/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `Allow from localhost` results in `client denied by server configuration`

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure your mod_proxy_ajp module is enable in Apache.

```
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
```

Once that is done put below code in your VirtualHost with relevant host details.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass           /   ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse    /   ajp://localhost:8009/
```