# Run multiple tomcat instances on same port

Tags: windows, tomcat, server, port

Is it possible to run multiple instances of Tomcat on same server (Windows Server 2016) with same port number

Example:
If https://example.com/app1 -> use tomcat1

If https://example.com/app2 -> use tomcat 2

I mean choosing tomcat based on URL request. 
Or you suggestion how to solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093298/running-multiple-instances-of-tomcat-on-same-port)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Multiple Instances of Tomcat on same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093298/running-multiple-instances-of-tomcat-on-same-port)